# What difference in cache implementation of firefox and chrome affected twitter?

Tags: firefox, cross-browser, browser-cache, w3c, web-standards

Twitter released [a statement](https://privacy.twitter.com/en/blog/2020/data-cache-firefox) that is worded and advertised in the severity of a data breach, where it blames it on differences in Firefox's implementation of caching. They are also greeting every firefox user with a prompt:
[image: a prompt].

I'd like to be aware of this difference, so it doesn't affect the websites I work on. The wording doesn't suggest a bug in the implementation, but it seems to blame Firefox. Assuming that it wasn't a bug, I'd like to know if Firefox's implementation is deviating from the standard, or if this is another case of the more popular's browser's implementation being considered the "standard."

Comment: Can you substantiate this a little? The mozilla blog from the posted answer seems to hint that there weren't any bugs which caused this, and it was adhering to the standards.

Comment: it appears I was totally off mark with my assumption, apologies

Answer (score 1):

a [detailed explanation was posted](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2020/04/twitter-direct-message-caching-and-firefox/) on Mozilla technical blog (although it's not entirely clear this [got to the exact set of heuristics](https://twitter.com/mnot/status/1247362614243532802) that was assumed)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Found the most concise answer in "What Website Developers Can Do" section. Will keep the bounty open till its expiration period.